# Wordpress select posts which have the category name the same as the title

Tags: wordpress

So, 
i've created a post type named slider for which i've used this code in order to retrieve it's posts:

```
 query_posts(array('post_type'=>'slider',
                      'posts_per_page'=>'20'
                      ));

    //loop
    if(have_posts()) : 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

i've found somewhere, that this code would work to display all posts that come from a category which has the same name as the page title:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

How can i combine this two?
I need the post slider type, this slides i've divided in categories, so i need to get only slider post types that have the category name as the title.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query_posts(array('post_type'=>'slider',
                  'posts_per_page'=>'20',
                  'category_name='.get_the_title()
            ));
```

And check the full documentation:

[Function Reference/query posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)